# I'm having difficulty fixing what I believe to be a double free

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a vector of linked lists as a class member. Valgrind shows that there are no memory leaks, but also produces Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() errors on program end.

I've tried to fix this by writing a destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator for the linked list. I believe these have been implemented correctly. I've also tried various methods of adding linked lists to the member vector (references, pointers, smart pointers), none of which seem to solve the problem.

```cpp
#include "lists.h"

lists::lists() {

}

void lists::newList() {
  int size, value;
  cout << "Please specify size of this list" << endl;
  cin >> size;
  shared_ptr<list> new_list(new list);
  //list *new_list = new list();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << "Enter value for node " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin >> value;
    new_list->pushBack(value);
  }
  list_storage.push_back(new_list);
  //delete new_list;
}

void lists::deleteList() {

}

void lists::display() {
  for (int i = 0; i < list_storage.size(); i++) {
    list_storage[i]->display();
  }
}
```

```cpp
#include "list.h"

list::list() {
  head = NULL;
}

list::list(const list& list) {
  head = NULL;
  node *current = head;
  while (current != NULL) {
    this->pushBack(current->data);
    current = current->next;
  }
}

list& list::operator=(const list& rhs) {
  list temp(rhs);
  swap(temp.head, head);
  return *this;
}

list::~list() {
  if (head != NULL) {
    node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
      node *next = current->next;
      delete current;
      current = next;
    }
    delete head;
  }
}
```

Here's the valgrind output:

```
==15967== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
...
==15967== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15967==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15967==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 10 frees, 74,856 bytes allocated
==15967== 
==15967== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==15967== 
==15967== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15967== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I removed big portion of the valgrind output because stackoverflow told me it was spam, but I can try to include it in a comment if needed.

Comment: in your while loop (list destructor), you delete current (which is head at the beginning), and the redelete head after the loop.

Comment: Your copy constructor is not working: it'll never enter the `while` loop, and never even mentions the original object `list`.

Comment: For a small list (three-four nodes) step through the code line by line in a debugger. Make notes on all nodes (their pointers more specifically). If you see that you happen do `delete` a node that was previously deleted, then it should hopefully give you a hint big enough to figure out the problem.

Comment: As you use smart pointers, you might avoid completely `new`/`delete`.

Comment: @learningthings `list::list(const list& list) {` -- That doesn't confuse you, naming the parameter the same as the type?  Also,   `head = NULL;  node *current = head;  while (current != NULL) {` -- That could never work, since `head` starts out as NULL and never changes.  In addition, the assignment operator using copy / swap (which is the right thing to do, IMO) **requires** that the copy constructor and destructor are bug-free and working.  Once you get those to work properly, then things should work correctly.  Then and only then will copy / swap in the assignment operator be beneficial.

Comment: FYI sanitizers usually give nicer error message than Valgrind, so if you can use clang or gcc you may want to try sanitizers in the future.

Comment: Side notes: a) I assume you have a reason (learning?) for not simply using `std::forward_list` (if a linked list is even sensible, which usually it's not). b) I highly suggest that you start writing (meaningful) unit tests (e.g. the no-op copy constructor could have been found that way). c) always build with debug symbols when debugging so that tools like Valgrind can provide a readable stack trace.

Comment: Thanks everyone I'll look into all of this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at your destructor :

```
list::~list() {
  if (head != NULL) {
    node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
      node *next = current->next;
      delete current;
      current = next;
    }
    delete head;
  }
}
```

entering the loop, you delete `current`, which is `head` at first iteration. After the loop you delete `head` again -> double free.